# img src concatenation fails

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a Image url which keeps changing depending upon the GUID which gets generated.So,for example,when i upload an image,it gets a name something like 
Image/hfghhf89d-uyfhfi9sih.png .So, i pass on the GUID to a session["dp"] and want to concatenate to the img src as below :

```
  var dp = '<%=Session["dp"]%>';
```

and

```
  <img src="Images/"+ dp +".png" id="target" alt="[Jcrop Example]"/>
```

But this doesnt work.Something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You're using single quotes, use double quotes.

```
<img src="Images/"+ dp +".png" id="target" alt="[Jcrop Example]"/>
```